# changing infowindow orientaion in google maps

Tags: google-maps, angularjs-directive, google-maps-markers

I am using angular-gm.js. I have created a customized marker and was able to open info window .I am looking for some examples where I can change infowindow to open left , right based on google marker position on either top left or bottom right. For now info window opens on top of marker by default

Answer (score 0):

An InfoWindow may be attached either to a Marker object (in which case its position is based on the marker's location) or on the map itself at a specified LatLng. By default the infowindow will open on the top of the marker(if attached to a marker), but you can use the pixeloffset to move the infowindow in relation to the marker.

from the docs:

"pixelOffset contains an offset from the tip of the info window to the location on which the info window is anchored. In practice, you should not need to specify this field. You can leave it at the default value."

```
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString,
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(100,0)
  });
```

The above causes the infowindow to open to the 100 pixels to the right of the marker. For more info on these properties of the infowindow please check out the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

I hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I wanted to change orientation of info window.. like if I want to open on right and left..or if inverted..how that can be done? I am using angular-min.js.

Comment: angular-gm.js the lib name